# Flutter: How to encode Timestamp with JSON?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Is there a way to convert `Timestamp` object to JSON other than DateTime? It shows an exception `Converting object to an encodable object failed.` How can I resolve this?

Exception: `JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Timestamp')`

Code:

```
class QRGen extends StatefulWidget {
  Timestamp bustime1;
  Timestamp bustime2;
  QRGen(
      this.bustime1,
      this.bustime2,
      {super.key});

  @override
  State<QRGen> createState() => QRCodeDisplay();
}

class QRCodeDisplay extends State<QRGen> {
  late Timestamp bustime1;
  late Timestamp bustime2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bustime1 = widget.bustime1;
    bustime2 = widget.bustime2;
  }
  //const QRCodeDisplay({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Map<String, dynamic>
    var myData = {
      'bustime1':bustime1, 'bustime2':bustime2,
    };
    String encodedJson = jsonEncode(myData);
```

Comment: it can be more helpful if you provided sample code and an example.

Comment: I've updated my question, please reread it.

Comment: convert it to [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) seconds

Comment: Do you mean DateTime? I'm not sure if Firestore accepts DateTime as well.

Comment: no, i don't mean `DateTime`, i mean simple integer

Comment: So it's Timestamp to int?

Comment: did you check `Timestamp` class documentation?

Comment: Wow, it sounds short, simple and clean.